# Powershell FTPWebRequest and EnableSsl = True

Tags: powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I searched this site and found an FTPWebRequest example via Powershell. I put it to use and it works fine. However, when I enable SSL via EnableSsl=$True, all I get is timeouts or a delayed "227 Entering Passive Mode", which breaks the process. As soon as I disable EnableSsl, I can fly right through. Can someone point me in the right direction? SSL is supported on the FTP host.

I'd eventually like change the method to DownloadFile and loop the code to download files, after I get the list and find matches. I'd like to do it securely, though.

```
# Create an FTPWebRequest object to handle the connection to the FTP server
$ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($sourceuri)

# Set the request's network credentials for an authenticated connection
$ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

# Set FTPWebRequest method to ListDirectory
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectory
$ftprequest.EnableSsl = $True
$ftprequest.UseBinary = $False
$ftprequest.UsePassive = $True
$ftprequest.KeepAlive = $False

$ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse()

Write-Out $ftpresponse.StatusCode
Write-Out $ftpresponse.StatusDescription
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Come to find out, spontaneous issue was server-side.